# PYTHON not showing all the output in IPython console in spyder 3.6

Tags: python, ipython

```
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
```

**#it shows output**

```
   X
   Out[3]: 

   array([['France', 44.0, 72000.0],
   ['Spain', 27.0, 48000.0],
   ['Germany', 30.0, 54000.0],
   ..., 
   ['France', 48.0, 79000.0],
   ['Germany', 50.0, 83000.0],
   ['France', 37.0, 67000.0]], dtype=object)
```

**TOTAL VALUES IS TEN BUT OUT OF TEN IT ONLY SHOWS UPPER THREE AND LOWER
    THREE VALUES TOTAL SIX VALUES.**

Comment: Yes, by default `ipython` doesn't print giant arrays, note the `...`

Comment: how i can see the whole list